# post photo to friend wall through graph api

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to post a photo to one of friends wall using the new graph api. For this I have the following code:

```
$attachment = array(
   'message' => 'Posted a photo',
   'source' => '@' . realpath(PATH_TO_MY_PHOTO)
);

$facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);
$facebook->api('/'.$id_friend.'/feed?access_token='.$access_token, 'post', $attachment);
```

The problem is that the picture is not uploaded. I mean, it only post the message without any picture. This does not work either if I try to post on the current user wall.

Does anyone have any idea on how to achieve this ? Thanks.

p.s. I'm requesting only publish_stream permission

Comment: T4u ,I am also having same problem.I am trying to post an image to wall of facebook via graph api. if image is hosted any server,get posted but stored in local desktop(harddisk),image will not get posted.Throws an error saying that picture url is not properly formatted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to post a poto to a users wall, as in publishing a photo and not a stream story,
you can post to here:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/ALBUM_ID/photos.
```

for more information visit  [facebook's graph api photo documentation.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/)

Comment: i haven't got time to test this, but it looks like it should do the job.

Comment: can you just post to any album? aren't they private?

Answer (score 1):

You should replace "source" with "picture".

$imagepath='http://site.com/pic.jpg';

$attachment = array(
   'message' => 'Posted a photo',
   'picture' => $imagepath
);

$facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);
$facebook->api('/'.$id_friend.'/feed?access_token='.$access_token, 'post', $attachment)

You can optionally add some more fields. for more details:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

Comment: I'm sorry, but what you say publish a stream story, not uploads a photo to user „wall photos” album. Anyways, I did a workaround and I posted the photo to the current user wall and only tagged the friend in that photo.

Comment: @misterjinx, look at my new answer.